# Accessing Eager-Loaded Relationships When Lazy Loading in Async Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

Asyncio Sqlalchemy has the nifty `awaitable_attrs` that allows you to lazy load relationships you might otherwise be forced to eager load.
However, when you *do* lazy load relationship objects, those objects do not appear to execute their respective relationship loading strategies. For example:

```py
class Parent(Base):
   __tablename__ = "parent"

   children:Mapped["Child"] = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
  __tablename__ = "child"

   parent_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("parent.id")) 
   
   parent: Mapped["Parent"] = relationship("Parent")
   toys:Mapped[List["Toy"]] = relationship("Toy", lazy="selectin")
```

You would expect this:

```py
async with db_session:
   children = await parent.awaitable_attrs.children
print(children[0].toys)
# prints [Toy('thing'), Toy('other thing')]
```

but what you'll actually get is this

```bash
Error extracting attribute: 
DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance 'Child' is not bound to a Session; 
lazy load operation of attribute 'toys' cannot proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is semi-transparent in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncAttrs.awaitable_attrs) for `awaitable_attrs`:

> provide a namespace of ***all*** attributes on this object wrapped as awaitables.

(emphasis added by me)

All, in this case, means *all* - everything is lazy-loaded. The easiest way to return to the desired behavior of your eager-loaded relationships on lazy-loaded objects is to refresh them.

```py
async with db_session:
   children = await parent.awaitable_attrs.children
   [await db_session.refresh(c) for c in children] 
print(children[0].toys)
# now prints [Toy('thing'), Toy('other thing')] as expected!:w
```